# Interpreting ProcessingInstruction as space with itertext

Tags: python, lxml

I want to have all my text of a tag using lxml.etree._Element.itertext()

However, in my text I have PI and this does not generate space. Is there a parameter to do this? Or should I make a first pass by adding a space next to the PI if there is none?

```
<p><?PI ?>Some text<?PI ?>continue the text</p>
```

So with this exemple I want have:

> "Some text continue the text"

But have:

> "Some textcontinue the text"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the PI tag with a space.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '<p><?PI ?>Some text<?PI ?>continue the text</p>'
xml = xml.replace('<?PI ?>',' ')
text = ''.join(ET.fromstring(xml).itertext())
text.strip()
```

Comment: This does not allow me to have a space between 'text' and 'continue'. But the first PI does not generate a space, thanks

Comment: @tapafe I'm sorry that I forgot to add one line. I have edited my answer. Please check now.